# How to avoid vertical repetition for common name and family name?

Tags: django, django-models, database-design

In my model there are fields like `name` and `family name` that will be repeated. For example "John" or "Jack" are common names bound to repeat themselves.

Is there any better way or is this OK by normalization standards of data model design?

```
class PropertyOwner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Comment: Unless you plan to have tables that have data on the names (e.g. the years they were popular, or some other demographic data around the names), then what you have is fine. Don't overdo database normalization. Consider what your base entity or entities that your app is revolved around. If it's an app about names and their demographics, then yes, it makes sense to normalize down to the names, but if your app is about real estate and their property owners, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- **First Method**
Create a method in your model called **check_name_family_name**
that check if the name is a ready exists so your code after modification will be:

```
class PropertyOwner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
    def check_name_family_name(self):
        if self.__class__.object.filter(name = self.name,family_name=self.family_name):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

then in your view after :

```
obj = yourform_obj.save(commit=False):
if obj.check_name_family_name():
    obj.save()
else:
     return HttpResponse('error in  ...')
```

2- **2ed Method**
you can use in your form:

```
def clear_family_name(self):
    if PropertyOwner.object.filter(name = self.clean_data['name'],family_name=self.clean_data['family_name'):
        raise ValidationError('...')
    else:
        return self.clean_data['family_name']
```